# Generate all the points on the circumference of a circle

Tags: python

Could someone help me with a code that could generate all the points on the circumference of a circle, Given the radius and center of the circle. I need the code in Python. Also could someone explain what would happen if K-Means is applied to two sets of points (i mean the points on the circumference) for 2 circle with same center but different radius. How would the clustering happen.

Comment: There is an infinite number of points on the circumference of a circle. What exactly do you mean by "...generate all the points..."?

Comment: You can ask more than one question. It's not desirable to mix two unrelated questions like this.

Comment: Sorry I did not mention the number of points I wanted to restrict it to.

Comment: But I wanted to apply k-means to two different circles so i had to add it here.

Comment: @Beginner You weren't downvoted because of your question, you were downvoted because of the **quality** of the question.  You can edit your question and move the unrelated stuff to another question as Michael is suggesting and also improve your question if you like.

Comment: @Beginner: Please don't **add** comments to a question.  Please **update** the question to be perfectly clear.

Comment: What will happen with k-means depends on the radii of the two circles, the distance between the centers, and the value of k you choose.  Also, k-means is not deterministic.  There is some randomness, so the results will be somewhat different from one run to the next.  Again, it's difficult to know exactly what you are asking.  And no, you don't have to put it all in one question.  You have two questions: one is about generating some points on the circumference of a circle, and the other is about the k-means algorithm.  You'll get better answers if you ask two questions.

Answer (score 22):

The following would generate the desired number of points on a circumference of a circle centered at (0,0),default is 100 points.

```
import math
pi = math.pi

def PointsInCircum(r,n=100):
    return [(math.cos(2*pi/n*x)*r,math.sin(2*pi/n*x)*r) for x in range(0,n+1)]
```

Comment: Remember that you may end up with gaps in your circle if you only draw the points

Comment: Yah offcourse, and that reminds me `REPEAT 360 [FD 1 LT 1/360]`. I use to do this in my Class 7 Practical to draw a cricle :-).

Comment: how can I use the same code for a center other than 0,0

Comment: @SaurabhSaxena i edited the answer to work https://gist.github.com/danleyb2/ce6d2b82b1556f7bb7dc3c5d2bccb2fc

Comment: Can you modify for n such circles of m points that circle where the n circles are arranged in a circle?

Comment: If you want this as a one liner and like ascii art
```(lambda r, n : print("".join(["00" if any((i == p[0] and j == p[1] for p in (lambda r, n : [[int((lambda x : 1 - (x**2)/2 + x**4/(4*3*2)  - x**6/(6*5*4*3*2))(2*3.1415/n*x)*r + r),int((lambda x : x - (x**3)/6 + x**5/(5*4*3*2) - x**7/(7*6*5*4*3*2))(2*3.1415/n*x)*r + r) ] for x in range(-int(n/2),int(n/2))])(r,n))) else "\n" if j >= n - 1 else "  " for i in range(n) for j in range(n)])))(10,30)```

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to generate All points on the circumference of a circle.

```
def all_floats():
    for exp in xrange( -1024, 1024 ):
        for man in xrange( -(2**52), 2**52 ):
            yield (man/2**52)*2**exp

def all_circle( r=100, domain=all_floats ):
    for x in domain():
       for y in domain():
          if x**2 + y**2 == r**2:
              yield x, y
```

That can't be what you're looking for.  However, it was fun to write.

I think that this algorithm can be generalized for different `all_floats` style functions that general all values in different numeric domains.  `all_ints` would be trivial.  `all_decimal` might be fun to write, also.

Comment: radius = 10
steps = 100

t = []
angleStep = pi * 2 / steps
 
for a in range(0, steps):
    x1 = sin(a * angleStep) * radius
    y1 = cos(a * angleStep) * radius
   
    t.append([x1,y1])

Comment: That wasn't ALL the points on the circumference, just those representable in Python's floating point number format :-)

Comment: @Beginner it's best not to put code in the comments.  It's generally best for making **short** points and asking questions for clarity, and sometimes but not ideally, quips ;)

Comment: @Dave: I'm not sure what hair you're splitting.  What representation of point do you suggest?  The mathematical ideal is infinite, and not useful for digital computers.  Are you suggesting some other representation?  What -- specifically -- should be used here?  I have modified things so that other representations would be tolerated.

Comment: @S.Lott: The smiley was supposed to indicate that my comment was offered in the same spirit as your code.  It is mathematically impossible to enumerate the set of real numbers, just as it's computationally impossible to visit every member of the set of floating point numbers on any computer.  Cheers.

Comment: @Dave: I thought you might have had some domain that better fit the undefined **all** in the question.  I was hoping.  After all, there are a lot of number-like domains.  Maybe you had a cool, new tricky one hidden up your sleeve.  Like, maybe, the rational fractions of (int,int) pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Never implemented this myself, but [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) might be a start. It even has an example implementation, you only need to translate it to Python. :) Doesn't help with the k-means part of your question, though.